# Pydev Eclipse executes previously executed program before executing current program

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have a single project which contain multiple pydev module programs. None of the modules are inter-linked or imported into other modules. All are independent modules.
I am seeing an issue with two programs namely: "CmdOnRemoteServer" and "ipaddress"

When i execute program "CmdOnRemoteServer" program, the console prints the output of previous/old program "ipaddress" and then jumps into the current program "CmdOnRemoteServer" and prints the output.
I could find this behaviour by putting the program debug and having breakpoints in both programs.

In the Preferences>>Run/Debug>>Launching, the options selected are "Launch the selected resource or active editor" and "If not launchable>>Launch the previously launched application"

I added 'if ____name____ == "____main____":' code to "CmdOnRemoteServer", but this also didnt help.
I am attaching the debug screenshot which shows both programs listed in the mainthread.
[image]

Can someone please help me with this issue?

As requested, adding the code to the question:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    remoteServer=winrm.Session("IDCQEAM190.amdom009.lab", auth = ("Administrator", "Control123"))
remoteCMD = remoteServer.run_cmd("ipconfig", ["/all"])

myfile = open(r"C:\Users\pshastri\Desktop\remoteServer.txt", "w")
myfile.write(remoteCMD.std_out)
myfile.close()

myfile = open(r"C:\Users\pshastri\Desktop\remoteServer.txt", "r")
ipPatt = "IPv4 Address[\.\s]{1,}:\s[\d+\.]{1,}"
hostPatt = "Host Name [\.\s]{1,}: [A-Za-z0-9]+"
domPatt = "Primary Dns Suffix [\.\s]{1,}: [A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+"
myfile.seek(0)
ipReg = re.findall(ipPatt, myfile.read())
myfile.seek(0)
hostReg = re.findall(hostPatt, myfile.read())
myfile.seek(0)
domReg = re.findall(domPatt, myfile.read())
print "".join(ipReg), "\n", "".join(hostReg), "\n", "".join(domReg)
```

Comment: Did you add exactly `if ____name____ == "____main____": `? Because if so, this is invalid python syntax and you should instead type `if __name__ == "__main__": `. Also, can you add your code for CmdOnRemoteServer?

Comment: No that is due to the text formatting here. I would have got some compilation error if i had put the incorrect syntax.
Adding the code to main question.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on your debug stacktrace, the problem seems to be that you're program (**CmdOnRemoteServer**) ends up in a chain where the Python standard library imports an **ipaddress** module (so, to fix the error, rename your **ipaddress** module to something else as that name is already used in the standard library).

Comment: I did rename the ipaddress file to myaddress. This time i dont see the file in the debug trace even though i have put the breakpoint in the file. But the output of the myaddress file prints before printing the CmdOnRemoteServer output

Comment: Well, I can't really debug what you have there... my suggestion is for you to raise an exception where it prints and see the stack trace to try to discover what may be wrong (you may want to remove all the .pyc files to make sure there are no leftovers from the previous module too).